# Can I buy stocks on Vanguard SIPP from UK

Tags: investing, united-kingdom, vanguard, pension-sipp

I currently have a SIPP account with HL. But I want to transfer my account to Vanguard as the annual account fee is much cheaper with Vanguard. However I don’t know and couldn’t find any information that we can buy stocks also on vanguard SIPP platform. I searched their website and google but unfortunately I only find details about buying ETF and other funds but no information on buying stocks and the charges for each transaction. Should I presume that any SIPP provider lets us buy stocks and funds.
Thanks
X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that Vanguard's platform is tied to their products and **only** lets you buy the things (funds and ETFs - all Vanguard's own products) listed here:
https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/what-we-offer/all-products

If you *want* to hold other things, then Vanguard's platform probably isn't for you.  Although if it works out considerably cheaper you should ask yourself whether you really *need* those other things.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I decided to transfer my SIPP to Vanguard considering the much lower fees. I will buy the stocks from my Shares ISA account.